# Colorings in 3D and beyond with equal number of black and white neighbours

Tags: geometry, coloring, combinatorial-geometry

Represent the three-dimensional space as a grid of unit cubes. Is there a way to colour each cube in black or white so that each cube has half of its $26$ neighbours (sharing a common side, face, or just a vertex) black and half of them white? What about higher dimensions?

For two dimensions it is certainly possible - perform the standard chessboard colouring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In three dimensions, stack two layers of standard chessboard together with matching squares in the third dimension.  Now stack these bilayers with the squares mismatched.  Each cube has $8$ neighbors in its plane, of which $4$ are each color.  It has $9$ neighbors in the layer above and $9$ in the layer below.  $5$ of the ones in the layer above match $4$ in the layer below.

I believe you can continue the pattern to as many dimensions as you want.  For $4D$, take two of the above $3-$spaces and stack them with matching faces.  Then take bilayers and stack them offset.  The $26$ neighbors in a layer are equally split and the layer above and below are staggered so the remaining $54$ neighbors are evenly split.